# Can WIndows 10 make a "virtual surround sound" with multiple speakers?

Tags: windows-10, audio

Can Windows 10 use a soundbar for left/right, the internal laptop speaker for center speaker, and a portable BT speaker as rear speakers? If so, how do I do so?

Comment: No, not really. Not until someone writes a specific software that can do that anyway.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - it's not that the computer can't do it, it's that it can't do it without recognisable 5.1-capable hardware. 5.1 routing is already built into the OS, it just cannot be enabled without appropriate hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This function is not built in or native to Windows. It would require a driver and controller software that ran all of the speakers to support this function. I am not aware of such a product, though, perhaps something like Virtual Audio Cable may be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done without additional hardware [& even then not in the way you want it to].

Your computer has no way to route 5 [should be 6] separate audio channels. It is built to handle two, & is also wired to be able to send just two to any external device.

You could buy an external DAC for about $£€15 on eBay which would allow the computer to recognise & route 6 channels [5.1] but you would then need to connect some kind of compatible audio system to that. You still could not use your laptop speaker as one of the 6. [BTW, bluetooth suffers from high latency & is not really suited to running 'cinema' or any time-sensitive audio at all.]